# Extract the url from <link rel=shortlink> in header of current document

Tags: javascript, dom

Given the following HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="http://example.com/g/8c" rel="shortlink" />
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

How would I retrieve the contents of href="" in the `link, rel=shortlink` with javascript? I don't know if such items in the head are accessible in the DOM.

The *head*-tag may contain more link-tags, for assets such as css. The *head*-tag may contain more then one link-shortlink (as per HTML5 'specs'), in that case, just pick the first.

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to do that?

Comment: For "share/tweet this page" functionality, where I want to pass the self-defined shortlink, rather then the `document.URL`, which will be shortened with some arbitrary 3rd party shortner.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?  All the current answers seem to be jQuery.

Comment: I have jQuery, but would rather write this specific function independent of jQuery, for portability reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `document.head` to get the head, and then use `getElementsByTagName` to get the `link` tags.

```
var links = document.head.getElementsByTagName('link');
for(var link in links){
    if(links.hasOwnProperty(link)){
        var l = links[link];
        if(l.rel === 'shortlink'){
          console.log(l.href);
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: `document.head` might not work in all browsers (by that, I mean it might not work in IE).  If it's not working try this:

```
document.head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do this with jQuery:

```js
$('link[rel=shortlink]').eq(0).attr('href');
```

Where:

- `$('link[rel=shortlink]')` selects the appropriate elements
- `eq(0)` selects the first of these
- `attr('href')` selects the appropriate attribute

Answer (score 2):

Well with jQuery I would do:

```
var link_href = $('link', 'head').attr('href');
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I know I asked javascript, but since the general idea is the same in both plain-ol-js and jQuery, a downvote seems an overreaction, not?

Comment: I'm assuming it was downvoted because he never said he was using jQuery, and shouldn't need it just do to one task.

Comment: While your example works for my given HTML, it will fail if other link-tags are present, such as for CSS. Other answers to this question do take that in consideration.